# AWS Lex + QnA stack lambda 424 error when coupled with Interactions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I'm building a question and answer bot using the [QnA launch stack](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-question-and-answer-bot-with-amazon-lex-and-amazon-alexa/#deploying). After training some questions in the bot designer, I am able to interact with it there as well as directly within lex indicating that the lambda function associated with QnA is working as intended. However, when creating a react app and setting it up with [interactions](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/interactions/chatbot/q/framework/react#props-slots-amplify-chatbot), I get a lambda 424 errors. This works with sample bots (orderflower, booktrip etc.) and with bots I have made previously using the same launch stack.

Going through the logs i get the following invoke error:

```
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot convert undefined or null to object",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object",
        "    at Array.preprocess (/var/task/lib/middleware/2_preprocess.js:130:31)"
    ]
}
```

[image: See image of logs here]

This points me to the following code on [github](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-ai-qna-bot/blob/master/lambda/fulfillment/lib/middleware/2_preprocess.js). What I gather from here is that interactions is not sending a jwt? I'm not sure how to resolve this as I haven't encountered this error previously with my bots and it is working with bots i've built previously using the same launch stack. I deployed across different regions jsut to confirm it wasn't a deployment issue but encountered the same 424 error..

Any help/guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, have similar issue while accessing or calling from Amazon Alexa skill. It does come back with launch request response but further any questions it doesn't. Looks like you have been working on the same stack as mine, should we catch to go thru the steps over email?

Comment: hey @Geniuslead - i posted this on the associated github respository and they have noted this as being an issue with the setting of the lex sessionAttributes. It has currently been actioned and will hopefully be resolved soon! https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-ai-qna-bot/issues/229